Force an async method to stop running it's code
Is there a way to force an async method to stop running? Or is there a simple way to add support to stop running an async method?
I have this code that a user can start by clicking a start button:
async runTests() {
      await this.test1();
      await this.test2();
      await this.test3();
      await this.test4();
      await this.test5();
      await this.test6();
      await this.test7();
      await this.test8();
      await this.test9();
      await this.test10();
}

But now I need a way to stop it.
Is there a way to cancel this call or to exit out of it midway?
I would love something like,
window.cancelAsyncFunction(this.runTest);

Note: Typescript converts async calls into I believe some pseudo async JavaScript so I believe it's possible to manually cancel it somehow but there would be benefits to having a native call if one exists.

Here is the code generated by Typescript:
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(b, p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    };
    return function (d, b) {
        if (typeof b !== "function" && b !== null)
            throw new TypeError("Class extends value " + String(b) + " is not a constructor or null");
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
var __generator = (this && this.__generator) || function (thisArg, body) {
    var _ = { label: 0, sent: function() { if (t[0] & 1) throw t[1]; return t[1]; }, trys: [], ops: [] }, f, y, t, g;
    return g = { next: verb(0), "throw": verb(1), "return": verb(2) }, typeof Symbol === "function" && (g[Symbol.iterator] = function() { return this; }), g;
    function verb(n) { return function (v) { return step([n, v]); }; }
    function step(op) {
        if (f) throw new TypeError("Generator is already executing.");
        while (g && (g = 0, op[0] && (_ = 0)), _) try {
            if (f = 1, y && (t = op[0] & 2 ? y["return"] : op[0] ? y["throw"] || ((t = y["return"]) && t.call(y), 0) : y.next) && !(t = t.call(y, op[1])).done) return t;
            if (y = 0, t) op = [op[0] & 2, t.value];
            switch (op[0]) {
                case 0: case 1: t = op; break;
                case 4: _.label++; return { value: op[1], done: false };
                case 5: _.label++; y = op[1]; op = [0]; continue;
                case 7: op = _.ops.pop(); _.trys.pop(); continue;
                default:
                    if (!(t = _.trys, t = t.length > 0 && t[t.length - 1]) && (op[0] === 6 || op[0] === 2)) { _ = 0; continue; }
                    if (op[0] === 3 && (!t || (op[1] > t[0] && op[1] < t[3]))) { _.label = op[1]; break; }
                    if (op[0] === 6 && _.label < t[1]) { _.label = t[1]; t = op; break; }
                    if (t && _.label < t[2]) { _.label = t[2]; _.ops.push(op); break; }
                    if (t[2]) _.ops.pop();
                    _.trys.pop(); continue;
            }
            op = body.call(thisArg, _);
        } catch (e) { op = [6, e]; y = 0; } finally { f = t = 0; }
        if (op[0] & 5) throw op[1]; return { value: op[0] ? op[1] : void 0, done: true };
    }
};

And the method that has been transpiled:
    MyClass.prototype.runTests = function () {
        return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
            return __generator(this, function (_a) {
                switch (_a.label) {
                    case 0: return [4 /*yield*/, this.test1()];
                    case 1:
                        _a.sent();
                        return [4 /*yield*/, this.test2()];
                    case 2:
                        _a.sent();
                        return [4 /*yield*/, this.test3()];
                    // ... trimmed out more cases
                    case 3:
                        _a.sent();
                        this.updateStatus("Tests complete!");
                        return [2 /*return*/];
                }
            });
        });
    };

Sleep method that is mentioned in the comments:
   sleep(ms) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
   }

Calling sleep:
await this.sleep(10);


You can iterate your tests and stop with a class variable:


class Test {
  constructor(){
    for(let i=1;i<=10;i++){
      this[`test${i}`] = () => new Promise(r=>setTimeout(r, 250)); 
    }
  }
  async runTests() {
     this.running = true;
     const tests = Array.from({length:10}, (_, i) => this[`test${i+1}`]);
     let i = 0;
     for(const test of tests){
        console.log(`running test ${++i}`);
        await test();
        if(!this.running){
          return;
        }
     }   
  }
  stop(){
    this.running = false;
  }
}

const test = new Test;
test.runTests();
<button onclick="test.stop()">STOP</button>



A more sophisticated approach would be to use AbortController which you can cancel fetch with for example:


class Test {
  constructor(){
    for(let i=1;i<=10;i++){
      this[`test${i}`] = async (id, signal) => {
        try{
          const r = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/' + id, {signal});
          return r.json();
        }catch(e){
          if(e instanceof DOMException && e.name==='AbortError'){
            console.log(`fetch aborted`);
            return null;
          }
          throw e;
        }
      };
    }
  }
  async runTests({signal}) {
     let running = true;
     signal.addEventListener('abort', () => running = false);
     const tests = Array.from({length:10}, (_, i) => this[`test${i+1}`]);
     let i = 0;
     for(const test of tests){
        console.log(`running test ${++i}`);
        console.log(`result:`, JSON.stringify(await test(i, signal)));
        if(!running){
          return;
        }
     }   
  }
}

const test = new Test;
const ctrl =  new AbortController;
test.runTests(ctrl);
<button onclick="ctrl.abort()">STOP</button>




It should be noted that this will only abort between tests, it won't interrupt a test in progress.

In my case, I'm ok with that. I have some existing code that exits from functions by throwing an error and it's not the most elegant solution. This solution will work for tests for the most part. But if they are long tests then I that's correct; the test would have to finish running. To exit from a running function it would have to interrupt it somehow. Maybe extending the method and then calling the super method which sleeps for a bit and checking the class variable inside that. (again not elegant but it works).

If your async code consists of fetch calls, you can use an AbortController to cancel the request.
Otherwise when you create your promise, you'd need to expose a way to resolve or reject it externally.
